# php error with completely wrong, not even possible filepath

Tags: php

The issue I am having is kind of amazing me, never seen something that is truly impossible happen to me before.

What I see is that when trying to access a specific file, php is making up a random filepath that is completely none existant.

```
$less_template      = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'less/template.less';
$css_template       = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'css/template.css';
$less_resp          = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'less/responsive.less';
$css_resp           = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'css/responsive.css';
```

These are where the filepaths being called are being generated.

```
Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect.
File(/home/rem/www/outpost/ashl/templates/default/less/template.less) 
is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/rehost.ca/httpdocs/rehost/:/tmp/) in 
/var/www/vhosts/rehost.ca/httpdocs/rehost/a/ashl/ashl/templates/default/less/lessc.inc.php 
on line 1741
```

Now given that this error (to me anyway) is about as possible as dividing by 0, I must be totally overlooking something. This worked before but now it just does not.

To give a bit more information the filepath its looking for is from before a move. That does not change the fact to me that its impossible though as its referenced by a global constant.

Just to explain my standpoint on this, I never had this happen to me before and never thought it was possible for PHP to do such an illogical thing, so I don't even know where to start to even think about fixing it. Everything causing the error is global.

Please correct me if I am over thinking this, this is just confusing me like crazy.

NOTE:

I have attempted disabling open_basedir with no effect (according to an answer).

I have disabled any and all kinds of caching.

I have "checked" individual cache files before disabling to ensure file paths were correct (they were).

Comment: try with realpath, http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Comment: Your templates are cached

Comment: Which path is the impossible one? Also, I'm assuming you are using shared hosting.

Comment: I already checked the cache, there is no php cache, less cache, even browser cache (not that it would cause that). And it is dedicated hosting.

Comment: You are saying that you move the application to a different server? According to the error you get an `open_basedir` restriction, probably you have to set add the path to your application in the virtual host configuration.

Comment: open_basedir only stopped the error from showing, but did not fix it. This is also a multi site setup, and this is the only site having the issue, there are over 50 sites on it so i highly doubt php configuration (all use less).

Answer (score 1):

So which path is the "impossible" one? Do the files exist under `/home/...` or under `/var/www/...`? Which path are you accessing the files under?

I would assume the file exists under the `/home/...` path now and you have a symlink under `/var/www/...` that points to the `/home/...` path. Apache is probably pointing to the symlink in the vhost and so the file being requested by apache under `/var/www/...`, but really exists under `/home/...` which is why `__FILE__` returns the actual path under `/home/...` (php generated this path) but is reporting that the file loaded (which it gets from apache) is under `/var/www/...`. This would explain why the error reports that the file being loaded exists under `/var/www/...` but the php constant `__FILE__` reports where the actual file is located.

To fix, you should point your vhost to the right path, not a symlink. You could also add the `/home/...` path to the `open_basedir` in php.ini, but you said turning off open_basedir didn't fix the problem. You could also create your own constant and use that.

Comment: I will look deeper based on this, I do not think this is the case but it is the best lead so far and a very clear answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Disable the [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) restriction in your PHP configuration.